# Temporary tables vs unlogged tables performance in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I want to know about the Temporary tables vs unlogged tables performance in PostgreSQL?
I mean which is more fast for read and write operations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both are equally fast, since both bypass WAL.

The only difference is that temporary tables are cached in process private memory, governed by the [`temp_buffers`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-TEMP-BUFFERS) parameter, while unlogged tables are cached in [`shared_buffers`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-SHARED-BUFFERS). So the size of these parameters will affect the performance.

Comment: what is difference in size of these buffers?

Comment: You can set them however you want, so you can determine the difference.